# Unslider arrow formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css, unslider

I'm trying to use Unslider on my website, but the prev/next arrows are placed incorrectly on the sides the bottom of the slider, and not in the center. I have not done any changes to the Unslider CSS, but only styled the my-slider container.

I'm not able to figure out, how to have the arrows in the center of the content container without using absolute position. Could you please suggest, what could be the issue?

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left">
                Originální pouzdra a obaly<br/>
                Tvorba portfolia<br/>
                Fotoalba<br/>
                Autorské knihy
            </div>
            <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="img/logo.png"></a></div>
            <div class="right">
                Soukupová Petra<br/>
                soukupova.petra@gmail.com<br/>
                +420 123 456 789
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        <div class="content">
            <section>
                <div class="my-slider">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/petra_soukopova_projekt1.jpg" alt="Projekt 1"></li>
                        <li>Another slide</li>
                        <li>My last slide</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section>
                Bla Bla Bla
            </section>

            <section>
                Bla Bla Bla
            </section>
        </div>

    <footer></footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/unslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.my-slider').unslider();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

header {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}

.content {
    width: 1052px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 2;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 2;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

section {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

.my-slider {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Unslider css:

```
.unslider{overflow:auto;margin:0;padding:0}

.unslider-wrap{position:relative}

.unslider-wrap.unslider-carousel>li{float:left}

.unslider-vertical>ul{height:100%}

.unslider-vertical li{float:none;width:100%}

.unslider-fade{position:relative}

.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;z-index:8}

.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li.unslider-active{z-index:10}

.unslider li,.unslider ol,.unslider ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;border:none}

.unslider-arrow{
    position:absolute;
    left:120px;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.unslider-arrow.next{left:auto;right:120px}

.unslider-nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.unslider-nav ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unslider-nav ol li.unslider-active {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you don't "or can't" want to use `position: absolute;`. This is by far the easiest way to center elements based off a container. Also setting up a jsfiddle will get you help quicker.

Comment: You should view a slider as a container which displays data, eventually giving user control over what is displayed. Apart from the slider container, which should take up its necessary space from document flow, there's no point (that i'm aware of) why you shouldn't use `position:absolute;` for positioning any slider component, be it slides or controls. In fact, `position:absolute;` is by far the best way to display slider contents, while animating, without having any downside. Could you clarify why you don't want this particular attribute to have this particular value for the given component?

Comment: On a different note, it is very good you added the code you use, but please note it would be a lot easier for SO users to help if you used the snippet tool (`<>` button) to create a [mcve] from the code you already placed in your question. By not doing it, you're having whoever chooses to help you do it themselves, increasing the required effort for providing an answer for your question.

Comment: @RobScott thank you for your comments. Actually, it's not that I don't want to use absolute position, I'm not able to figure out how to use the absolute position in regard to positioning the element to the center of the specific container - when I use top: 50%; its just centers the arrow to the center of the whole page, not the center of the slider container. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for the heads/up, I will make sure to use those in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@RobScott I've just figured it out. I was missing position: relative in the outer content class. Thanks again!